Error "KeyExcludedFromSecondaryIndexMessage" When Using get_program_accounts for SPL Token on Solana
I'm attempting to retrieve the top 100 holders of a specific SPL token on the Solana blockchain using the solana-py library in Python. However, I keep encountering an error that prevents me from successfully executing the request. Below is the code I'm using and the error message I'm receiving.
My code
import asyncio
from solana.rpc.async_api import AsyncClient
from solana.rpc.types import MemcmpOpts
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey

async def main():
    client = AsyncClient("https://stylish-old-aura.solana-mainnet.quiknode.pro/1a4382c827a0475355ebd4d32ed17403c3d5d0e4")
    
    spl_token_program_id = Pubkey.from_string("TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA")
    
    # $sol for test
    mint_address_str = "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112"
    
    
    try:
        mint_address = Pubkey.from_string(mint_address_str)
    except ValueError:
        print(f"Error: '{mint_address_str}' in not valid Solana Pubkey.")
        await client.close()
        return
    
    memcmp_opts = MemcmpOpts(offset=0, bytes=str(mint_address))
    filters = [memcmp_opts]
    
    try:
        resp = await client.get_program_accounts(
            pubkey=spl_token_program_id,
            encoding="jsonParsed",
            filters=filters
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error with get_program_accounts: {e}")
        await client.close()
        return
    
    if resp.value is None:
        print("Error: ", resp)
        await client.close()
        return
    
    accounts = resp.value
    
    holder_balances = {}
    
    for acc in accounts:
        
        account_data = acc["account"]["data"]["parsed"]["info"]
        owner = account_data["owner"]
        amount_str = account_data["tokenAmount"]["amount"]
        amount = int(amount_str)
            
        if owner in holder_balances:
            holder_balances[owner] += amount
        else:
            holder_balances[owner] = amount
    
    sorted_holders = sorted(holder_balances.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)
    
    top_100_holders = sorted_holders[:100]
    
    for rank, (holder_pubkey, total_amount) in enumerate(top_100_holders, start=1):
        print(f"{rank}. Holder: {holder_pubkey}, Amount: {total_amount}")
    
    await client.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

Error Message:
Error calling get_program_accounts: KeyExcludedFromSecondaryIndexMessage { message: "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA excluded from account secondary indexes; this RPC method unavailable for key" }
What I've Tried So Far:
Adjusted Offset in MemcmpOpts: Tried using both offset=0 and offset=8 to filter by the mint address, but the error persists.
Switched RPC Providers: Changed the RPC endpoint to https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com from QuikNode, but the error remains.
I would like to know if there are alternatives to get the list of token holders? Perhaps a different library or other methods. Is it possible to do this without spending money to buy a powerful RPC?

The get program account is very expensive. It would basically get all token accounts on solana which is millions. So its ususally disabled or ratelimited.
You could try pay for an RPC and maybe there is one that has token accounts cached or search for a token API from rpc providers.
The public endpoint will for sure not work. The error message hints hat maybe quicknode has a secondary index that you can get with a higher tier. But i dont know. Maybe ask their support or their website.
